# Is there an online RegexBuddy-like regular expression analyzer?

Tags: regex

I'm looking for an online utility that will prettify and add explanatory comments to a regular expression.  Does one exist?

Comment: i have made some simple [regex-analyzer](http://foo123.github.io/examples/regex-analyzer/) and [regex-composer](http://foo123.github.io/examples/regex-composer/) online in javascript (which include a couple of twists as well)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I like the online tool: http://regexr.com

When you hover over the regular expression you will get an explanation of that part.

Comment: it's been almost 3 years from this post and this is still best online regex editor

Comment: How do I even select a language? Surely the syntax is not the same for various languages.

Comment: From RegExr's help: _RegExr uses your browser's RegExp engine for matching, and its syntax highlighting and documentation reflect the JavaScript RegExp standard._  Which makes it of marginal utility for determining differences between various regex implementations.

Comment: It doesn't seem to explain the "number of steps" like regexbuddy does, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: It's good, maybe the best online, and still easily outclassed by regex buddy. And I mean both for crazy power user productivity *and* for people who just want maximum ease of use, or even for learning the basics.

Answer (score 24):

For what it's worth, I also like:

- [regex101.com](http://regex101.com/), which is quite powerful, but technical. It features timing and steps taken results as well as permalinks for sharing a regex with explanation and test data.
- [regexper.com](http://www.regexper.com/), which draws railroad diagrams of regexes. The results are very nice to look at and easy to understand, but there are no textual explanations.

Both are free to use.

Comment: I find regex101 most usable in terms of syntax highlighting and explanation. +1 for that.

Comment: Of the ones mentioned/googled, regex101 just now worked best for a Python RE (evaluated on paste, works).

Answer (score 6):

There's a bunch of them listed in [Steven Levithan's blog](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/jrx-xregexp).

Comment: Some great links there.  I love this one: http://osteele.com/tools/reanimator/

Answer (score 6):

[regexpal](http://regexpal.com/) is the one I always use.  I prefer it to the Flash-based RegExr.

Answer (score 2):

I currently use http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl from Rick Measham. It is a regex explanation tool that simply works.