# Regular expressions and matching

Tags: php, expression

Here is a list of examples of PHP regular expressions examples. Maybe this helps someone, as admin/ or another user can't make clear that I was trying to share my approaches.

[preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) does the search ([preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) is a replacer).

preg_match has three parameters - preg_match(FindWhat, FindWhere, GivingOutput);

**Example 1)**:

```
<?php
    // Everything expect letters and numbers
    $text = 'abc345fg@h';
    $newfilename = preg_match('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]/', $text, $out);
    echo $out[0];
?>
Output will be:
@
```

preg_match finds only one result (the firstly found result), with two options: [0] or [1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php).

**Example 2)**: find everything (any characters,words..) inside our search criteria:

```
<?php
    $text = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrst';
    $newfilename = preg_match('/ij(.*?)mn/', $text, $out);
    echo $out[0];
    echo $out[1];
?>
[1] -gives only the inner search result (what we had in the brackets,  between "ij" and "mn"):
kl

[0] -gives the whole search result:
ijklmn
```

(Note, that option [1](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) is not available if when you don’t use brackets in search criteria (as we have above, in example 1)

**Example 3)**:

If your target text has many same occurrences, like this:
$text = 'Hello user **Jimmy Jones**, it\'s me. Hello user **Mery Pawders**, it\'s still me.';

Now, here are two different matches, so, we need to use [preg_match_all](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php)

```
<?php
    $text = 'Hello user Jimmy Jones, it\'s me. Hello user Mery Pawders, it\'s me.';
    $newfilename = preg_match_all('/hello user (.*?) it\'s/', $text, $out);
    foreach ($out[1] as $found_one) {
        echo $found_one;
    }
    // Or use $out[0] for full search match
?>

Output will be:
Jimmy Jones,
Mery Pawders,
```

**Example 4)**: search among many possibilities:

```
<?php
    $text = 'member ACCOUNT7';
    preg_match("/ACCOUNT[123456789]/", $text, $out);
    echo $out[1];
?>

Output will be:
ACCOUNT7
```

**Example 5)**: To find a string, while input text contains new lines, you must use**s** at the end;

```
<?php
    $text = 'one
    two
    three';
    preg_match("/one(.*?)three/s", $text, $out);
    echo $out[1];
?>

Output will be:
two
```

**Example 6)**: Your search is always case sensitive. To make a case *insensitive* search, use **i** at the end (if you want, without **s**);

```
<?php
    $text = 'ONE TWO TREE';
    preg_match("/one(.*?)three/si", $text, $out);
    echo $out[1];
?>
```

**Example 7)**: to search for **special characters** (like /".<*'?, etc.) inside preg_match, you need to use this escape sign: \

```
<?php
    $text = 'hello Jimmy/Kroger ';
    preg_match("/Jimmy\/Kroger/", $text, $out);
    echo $out[0];
?>
```

Now, we can use the ^ operator, which searches for results conversely.

**Example 8)**: find everything rather than letters and numbers:

```
<?php
    $text = 'abc@*&^)($%';
    preg_match_all('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]/', $text, $out);
    foreach ($out[0] as $varr) {
        echo $varr;
    }
?>
Output will be:
@*&^)($%
```

For ***search*** and ***replace***, we have a bit different structure, as we need to use the new variable.

**Example 9)**: find and replace everything **rather than** letters and numbers with other character, using this operator: ^

```
<?php
    $text = 'ab2sq)(&*(%$%^$@%n23f9';
    $variable = preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9.]/', 'a', $text);
    echo $variable;
?>
Output will be:
ab2sqn23f9
```

**Example 10)**:  search and add something inside the found results:

```
<?php
    $text = 'Hi, it\'s me, Niko from Austria';
    $variable = preg_replace('/(Niko.*?) from/', '$1 Gomez', $text);
    echo $variable;
?>
Output will be:

it's me, Niko Gomez Austria
```

**Example 11)**: find all links inside text:

```
<?php
    $text = 'hi, my site is http://example.com, and on my page, at http://example.com/page37/blabla.html I wrote something..';
    preg_match_all("/[[:alpha:]]+:\/\/[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]\/]/",$text, $out);
    foreach($out[0] as $varr){
        echo $varr;
    }
?>
Output will be:
http://example.com
http://example.com/page37/blabla.html
```

**Example 12)**: like the example 11 (but with replace) - find links in text and put them in anchored tags:

```
<?php
    $text = 'Hi, my site is http://example.com, and on my page, at http://example.com/page37/trid.html I wrote something..';
    $variable = preg_replace("/[[:alpha:]]+:\/\/[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]\/]/",'<a href="\\0">\\0</a>', $text);
    echo $variable;
?>
```

Output will be the same sentence, but the links will be anchored.

1) *Tips: Do not use preg_match() if you only want to check if one string is contained in another string. Use stristr() or strpos() instead as they will be faster.*

2) **More advanced, specific examples about PHP regular expressions, use Google, or see **
*full options and manuals* at - http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php

(You can review shortly all operators list here -
 http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/15-php-regular-expressions-for-web-developers
http://www.noupe.com/php/php-regular-expressions.html
)

3) For HTML codes, there exist special light, PHP software, called- DOM Parser. But sometimes, if you know PHP regular expressions well, you might not need a DOM parser.

Comment: How would an email start with `Shop` and end with `0`? `SHOP_psgarden_0` is not a valid email address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
/^Shop.*0$/i
```

This one checks for a Shop at the beginning and a zero at the end.

Comment: but this one includes ^ mark. this means "opposite", doesnt it?
also, the above answer with many examples, was very good, why you have been non-satisfied?

Comment: No it means beginning and the dollar sign the end of an input. See also [this table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_Basic_Regular_Expressions) in wikipedia: *`^` Matches the starting position within the string. In line-based tools, it matches the starting position of any line.* and *`$` Matches the ending position of the string or the position just before a string-ending newline. In line-based tools, it matches the ending position of any line.*

Comment: thanks. i have to check, what does the ^&$ marks do.

Comment: @solutionfix See: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Comment: @solutionfix just for improving my answers what was more helpful for you in the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

I assume, when you say "$email", that you mean the stuff before the `@` sign. In that case you can use this regex:

```
$email = 'SHOP_psgarden_0@somewhere.com';
if (preg_match('/^shop.*0@/i', $email) === 1) {
    echo 'Yes!';
}
```

You can also check using normal procedural code:

```
$email   = 'SHOP_psgarden_0@somewhere.com';
$local   = substr($email, 0, strpos($email, '@'));
$amalgam = substr($local, 0, 4) . substr($local, -1);
if (strcasecmp('shop0', $amalgam) === 0) {
    echo "yes";
} else {
    echo "no";
}
```