# PHP Regex that matches everything after a certain character and ends with newline

Tags: php, regex

Im having propbles doing this regex to get everything after a certain character (* in this case) and ends with a newline in PHP.

I have:

```
texttextext
*Sometext
*othertext

texttextex
```

i want to be able to get "*Sometext and "*othertext" and add `<b></b>` to them.

Already tried with

```
$a = array( 
      "/\*(.*?)\n/is"
   ); 
   $b = array( 
      "<b>$1</b>"
   );
   $texto = preg_replace($a, $b, $texto);
```

but it does not work. What im doing wrong?

Comment: so you want to add the <b> tag every time you have a * in front of each line and make that entire line bold?

Comment: Try downloading the Regex Coach.

Answer (score 1):

```
"/^\*(.*?)\n/im"
```

You just have to add `^` to match the beginning of the line. This requires the `/m` multiline flag.

The `/s` flag however was wrong there, as that allowed `.*` to also match linebreaks - which you do *not* want.

Comment: One last question. It seems to work with * character, but fails to if i use the ">" character

Comment: Not sure. Can you show the complete regex you've tried? (`>` is not a metacharacter and should work as-is)

Comment: Also check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491930/is-there-an-online-regexbuddy-like-regular-expression-analyzer for some tools to verify.