# How to match all words that contain a given digit?

Tags: regex

I'm wondering how to match all words that contain a given digit?

I've looked at O'Reilly Regular Expressions Cookbook, but failed to get the idea.

**Case 1. Some characters are in front of the digit.(Solved)**

\b(\d+[^\s]+)\b

```
time=>123, address~4321
```

**Case 2. Some characters are followed by digit.(Solved)**

\b(\d+[^\s]+)\b

```
1234<=range, 321=>location
```

Case 3. Some characters are forth digit.

```
time~1325@range, address*4321%location
```

Case 4. Duplicate in a single line of Case1 or Case2 or Case3.

```
firstTime=12   secondTime=34 
429923<=firstRange                353534=>secondRange
A12345alpha      B9876beta
```

Comment: What do you call a "word"? Any character sequence with no space?

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491930/is-there-an-online-regexbuddy-like-regular-expression-analyzer

Answer (score 0):

Since you have defined a word to be any string that does not contain a white space, you might want to use something like this:

```
([^\s]*\d+.[^\s]*)\m
```

The `\m` flag should make the regex work across multiple lines.

Comment: @gpojd: Yeah, I could do it like that as well. I guess that yours is another way of getting the job done.

I have modified my answer.

Comment: @gpojd it will fail to match `A1B2C3` for instance

Comment: @fge, his original answer was identical to what I suggested. I only replaced `[^\s]` with `\S` for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Try and match `(\S*(?:\d\S*)*)` on your input. Again the `normal* (special normal*)*` pattern, with `normal` being `\S` (anything but a space character) and `special` being `\d+` (one or more digits):

```
fg@erwin ~ $ perl -ne 'print "Match: -->$_<--\n" foreach m/(\S*(?:\d+\S*))/gm' <<EOF
> firstTime=12   secondTime=34 
> 429923<=firstRange                353534=>secondRange
> A12345alpha      B9876beta
> EOF
Match: -->firstTime=12<--
Match: -->secondTime=34<--
Match: -->429923<=firstRange<--
Match: -->353534=>secondRange<--
Match: -->A12345alpha<--
Match: -->B9876beta<--
```

Depending on the regex engine you use, you may even use possessive quantifiers all along, or an atomic group to accelerate matching.

And if you want a book --> http://regex.info

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex that will match each "word" containing the digit "2".

```
\S*?2\S*
```

Change the 2 to any digit sequence you wish to match. If you wish to match Words containing a 2, 5 or 7, then use a character class:

```
\S*?[257]\S*
```