# Regular Expression (preg_match) match anything

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

This is how far I got.
This is working:

```
$urls = $this->match_all('/<a href="(http:\/\/www.imdb.de\/title\/tt.*?)".*?>.*?<\/a>/ms',
            $content, 1);
```

Now I wan't to do the same with a different site.
But the link of the site has different structure:
http://www.example.org/ANYTHING

I don't know what I am doing wrong but with this other site (example.org) it is not working.

Here is what I have tried

```
$urls = $this->match_all('/<a href="(http:\/\/www.example.org\/.*?)".*?>.*?<\/a>/ms',
    $content, 1);
```

Thank you for your help. Stackoverflow is so awesome!

Comment: It should match anything after this .org/ . As I said http://www.example.org/ANYTHING

Comment: The delimiter character should be a character that does not occur, or rarely occurs within the regex. So using `/` as a delimiter for URL-related regexes is a bad choice - use `#` or something, it will make your regex a lot more readable and debugable.

Comment: Since you are asking regex question after regex question, I think it might be time to enlighten you on [some tools that aid in constructing them](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world) -or- [online tools](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491930/is-there-an-online-regexbuddy-like-regular-expression-analyzer) and http://regular-expressions.info/ for an introduction. Be sure to read up on when to use [DOM vs. regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3650431/345031) (depends on proficiency, and if the html is always normalized+well-known).

Comment: you may want to parse the document using DOMDocument first to get the anchor tags. your above regex fails to find many possible anchor tags such as `<a target="_blank" href="http://www.imdb.de/title/tt{whatever}">`. it assumes the tag has no attributes before the href attribute.

Answer (score 3):

[ANYTHING](http://ANYTHING) is usually represented by `.*?` (which you already use in your original regex). You could also use `[^"]+` as placeholder in your case.

Comment: I have edited my question. It would be kind if you could take a look at it again. Thanks.

Comment: Well, then that's not your problem. Be sure to check out the related links.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want the following regular expression:

```
'/<a href="(http:\/\/example\.org\/.*?)".*?>.*?<\/a>/ms'
```

You can also use a different delimiter to avoid escaping the backslashes:

```
'#<a href="(http://example\.org/.*?)".*?>.*?</a>#ms'
```

Note the escaping of the `.` in the domain name, as you intend to match a literal `.`, not any character.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should help

```
/<a href="(http:\/\/www.example.org\/.*?)".*?>.*?<\/a>/ms
<a href="http://www.example.org/ANYTHING">text</a>
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => <a href="http://www.example.org/ANYTHING">text</a>
    [1] => http://www.example.org/ANYTHING
)
```

EDIT: I always find this site very useful for when i want to try out preg_match - http://www.solmetra.com/scripts/regex/index.php