# what does (?=.*[^a-zA-Z]) mean

Tags: regex

What does (?=.*[^a-zA-Z]) mean

I am a beginner in regex and not getting what does it mean .

Is it like, dot(.) means any character so `.*` means any character any number of times and `[^a-zA-z]` any one character except a-z and A-Z.
what string will match it?

Thanks,

Puneet

Comment: When you don't understand a regex such as this go to one of the online tools like http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ , paste in your reg ex, then hover over each part of the reg ex for a tool-tip explanation of what it does.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491930/is-there-an-online-regexbuddy-like-regular-expression-analyzer

Comment: I swear by having a play around with [The Regex Coach](http://www.weitz.de/regex-coach/) for working this sort of thing out. There's a bunch of alternatives, too, including some that are web based. Regex Coach (amongst other things) gives a description of the regex; here saying it's a "zero-width positive look-ahead assertion", which you can then use to find out what that means on [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is positive look ahead assertion.

That means that there are at least one symbol that is not `a-ZA-Z` to right from the point.

Example:

```
$ echo 12abc | grep -P '2(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])'
$ echo 12abc. | grep -P '2(?=.*[^a-zA-Z])'
12abc.
```

In the first line there are no `not a-zA-Z` after `2`. And the line will not be shown.

In the second line I've added point to the end. Now there is a `not a-zA-Z` after `2`. And the line will be found and shown.