# What does this regular expression mean /^[a-z]{1}[a-z0-9_]{3,13}$/

Tags: regex

Can someone elaborate the following regular expression:

```
/^[a-z]{1}[a-z0-9_]{3,13}$/
```

and also give some sample strings that satisfy this regular expression?

Comment: What is your regex engine?

Comment: @MauriceStam: Why would that matter? (OK, it's generally required to tag the appropriate language, but in this case, it's a pretty universal regex, unless we're targeting a POSIX BR engine).

Comment: @TimPietzcker Because there are differences. In this case because POSIX does not support greedy. However I agree this is not really common.

Comment: @MauriceStam: POSIX doesn't support *lazy* quantifiers, yes, but the anchors in this regex make that restriction irrelevant as well.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Lesson learned ;) thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explanation: `/^[a-z]{1}[a-z0-9_]{3,13}$/`

- `^` - Asserts the start of a string
- `[a-z]{1}` Matches exactly one character from a-z.
- `[a-z0-9_]{3,13}` Matches any character from a-z or 0-9 but the length range must between 3 to 13.
- `$` End

[Example](http://regex101.com/r/uZ1bL9)

Answer (score 6):

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `[a-z]{1}` matches one lower-case letter. The `{1}` is unneeded.
- `[a-z0-9_]{3,13}` matches 3 to 13 chars. In case-insensitive mode, in many engines it could be replaced by `\w{3,13}`
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

**Sample Matches**

```
abcd
a_000
a_blue_tree
```

See [demo](http://regex101.com/#pcre).

**General Answers to "What Does this Regex Mean?**

1. You can use a tool such as See [regex101](http://regex101.com/#pcre) to play with a regex. The right pane explains it token by token.
2. There are several explaining tools based on the same original Perl library, such as [this one](http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl?re=%5E%5Ba-z%5D%7B1%7D%5Ba-z0-9_%5D%7B3,13%7D$&.submit=Explain!), on which one of the answers is based.
3. The ultimate answer can be found in *Mastering Regular Expressions, 3rd Ed.* and several excellent online tutorials, including the [regex FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075) on this site.

Comment: (Careful, `\w` would also match uppercase letters.)

Comment: The second character class won't match upper case letters.

Comment: @Dtex `\w` does match underscores.

Answer (score 2):

[Check Explanation Here](http://rick.measham.id.au/paste/explain.pl?regex=/%5E%5Ba-z%5D%7B1%7D%5Ba-z0-9_%5D%7B3,13%7D%24/%20)

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
  ^                        the beginning of the string
  [a-z]{1}                 any character of: 'a' to 'z' (1 times)
  [a-z0-9_]{3,13}          any character of: 'a' to 'z', '0' to '9',
                           '_' (between 3 and 13 times (matching the
                           most amount possible))
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Comment: The slashes are regex delimiters, not part of the regex itself.

Answer (score 1):

It means:
Start(`^`) with one (`{1}`) lowercase character(`[a-z]`), then proceed with at least three (`{3,`) but with a maximum of 13 (`13}`) characters from the set of lowercase characters, underline and numbers(`[a-z0-9_]`). After that the end of line is expected (`$`).

`a000` satisfies the condition

Answer (score 0):

It matches a string starting with `a-z` followed by 3 to 13 characters from the character set `a-z`, `0-9` or `_`.

There are a number of [online tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491930/is-there-an-online-regexbuddy-like-regular-expression-analyzer) that will explain/elaborate the meaning of a regular expression as well as test them.

Answer (score 0):

```
Assert position at the beginning of the string «^»
Match a single character in the range between “a” and “z” «[a-z]{1}»
   Exactly 1 times «{1}»
Match a single character present in the list below «[a-z0-9_]{3,13}»
   Between 3 and 13 times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) «{3,13}»
   A character in the range between “a” and “z” «a-z»
   A character in the range between “0” and “9” «0-9»
   The character “_” «_»
Assert position at the end of the string (or before the line break at the end of the string, if any) «$»
```

Generated using [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: @ThomasJunk Whether the slashes are delimiters depends on the regex engine or the language in which it has been written which is not known in the question.

Comment: @jbaums I agree, therefore I have removed them. However I do not know of any language using that delimited syntax so the actual question should not have 'included' them ;).

Comment: So sorry Maurice... That is idiotic, don't know what happened. So... Subbu, did Maurice's answer your question? Please give us some feedback. :)