# Regex for accepting all type of phone numbers in javascript validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm currently using below regex for accepting phone numbers,

```
 /^\+?(\d[.\- ]*){9,12}(e?xt?\d{1,5})?$/;
```

But now I want it to accept following phone numbers also(specially Indian mobile and landlines):

+91 9970464878
+91-22-22221500
09970464878
9970464878

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2113908/what-regular-expression-will-match-valid-international-phone-numbers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation

Comment: It looks like [your regex already matches these phone numbers](https://regex101.com/r/tG0bK6/1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the 3 possiblities to the start of the regex.

This is the regex I once used on a similiar requirement :

```
^(?:(?:\+|0{0,2})91(\s*[\-]\s*)?|[0]?)?\d{10}$
```

**NOTE** - You will have to strip away all the hyphens, as I dont think they are really required for validations.

[Sample Test](https://regex101.com/r/tG0bK6/2)

Here is the [Regular Expression Analyzer](http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws?regex=%5E%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3A%5C%20%7C0%7B0%2C2%7D%2991%28%5Cs%2A%5B%5C-%5D%5Cs%2A%29%3F%7C%5B0%5D%3F%29%3F%5Cd%7B10%7D%24&env=env_js) explanation.

Comment: Does this [link](http://www.myezapp.com/apps/dev/regexp/show.ws?regex=%5E%28%3F%3A%28%3F%3A%5C+%7C0%7B0%2C2%7D%2991%28%5Cs*%5B%5C-%5D%5Cs*%29%3F%7C%5B0%5D%3F%29%3F%5Cd%7B10%7D%24&env=env_js) explain?

Comment: This [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2491930/is-there-an-online-regexbuddy-like-regular-expression-analyzer) has some great answers to Regex Analyzers